# Initialize new instance of an entity framework object with constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to use a constructor with EF entities?

I want to add a new instance of an Entity Framework entity and add it to a List<>

i.e.

```
List<MyObject> objectList = new List<MyObject>();
objectList.Add(new MyObject( "property" , 1);
```

instead of

```
List<MyObject> objectList = new List<MyObject>();
MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.Name = "property1";
object.ID = 1;
objectList.Add(object);
```

Comment: Do you understand that you're using constructors in both your samples? And while you can add parametrized constructors to Entity Framework entities, you may not need it to achieve code brevity you have in your first example. What and what for do you really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that.

Entity Framework Code First is all about *persistence ignorance*.  That is, you can write code the way you always have and the persistence part "just works".  In reality there are a few limitations on that goal, but for the most part it works as advertised.

Note that there must be a *parameterless* constructor as well (so that Entity Framework can instantiate instances of the object automatically).  But you can also have as many parameterized constructors as you want.